# Ignore cells from count in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm running a sheet to manage stock levels. When stock comes in, it is entered as a (positive) number, when stock goes out, it is recorded as a - (negative) number. I would like to ignore some numbers in a column when I sum the total if the row contains "Stock Take Level" in the description cell.

I need this so I can see what stock levels we had on whatever day I do a stock take.

It currently works like:

[image]

I would like it work like:

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

to ignore within sumif:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8; "<>Stock Take Level"; B2:B8)
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A2:A8<>"Stock Take Level"; B2:B8; )))
```